# Serial numbers of equal numbers next to each other in array

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int i, j, n;
    int num[5];
    int serial;

    for(i=0; i<5; ++i){
        scanf("%d",&num[i]);
        if(num[i]==num[i-1])
            serial=i;
        else
            continue;
    }
    printf("Serial number of equal numbers next to each other:%d. %d.", serial-1, serial);
}
```

This may be hard to understand because I'm not a native English speaker.
If the numbers next to each other are equal the program should print the serial number of those numbers.

For example:

```
Input: 1 2 3 7 7 7 6;
Output: 3. 4. 5.
```

Input: 5 5 5 5 5
Output: 0. 1. 2. 3. 4.

I made some changes now it prints the serial of two equal numbers.
I: 1 2 2 3 4 - O: 1. 2.
But what if all the numbers are equal?

Comment: What does your program do instead?

Comment: The expression `num[i]==num[i+1]` will compare an initialized part of the array with an uninitialized part (whose value is indeterminate), leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Tip: read all the numbers first and check them afterwards.

Comment: Also, if `n` is equal to or larger than `100` you will go out of bounds, and again have undefined behavior.

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `3, 4` then?

Comment: How did you get that program to print *two* numbers (since the edit, *three* numbers)? Also, if no two were the same, `serial` is *undefined*

Comment: How exactly do you think it makes sense to start a loop from 0 and then check `num[i-1]`? And why put `continue` at the very end of a loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
// ...

    // deal with index 0
    if (num[0] == num[1]) printf("0. ");

    // deal with indexes 1 .. N - 2
    for (int k = 1; k < n - 1; k++) {
        if ((num[k - 1] == num[k]) || (num[k] == num[k + 1])) {
            printf("%d. ", k);
        }
    }

    // deal with index N - 1
    if (num[n - 2] == num[n - 1]) printf("%d. ", n - 1);

// ... possibly with a printf("\n"); somewhere
```

Comment: [Both](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/94372?rskey=4Exb2B&result=1#eid) are [correct](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/index); thanks for the heads up :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this without storing the numers in an array, but you must keep track of how many equal numbers have been read before reading the present one:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        int i = 0;          // running index
        int prev = 0;       // previously read number
        int iprev = 0;      // start of range of equal numbers previously read
        int n;              // currently read number

        while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
            if (n != prev) {
                if (i - iprev > 1) {
                    while (iprev < i) printf("%d\n", iprev++);
                }
                iprev = i;
                prev = n;
            }

            i++;
        }

        if (i - iprev > 1) {
            while (iprev < i) printf("%d\n", iprev++);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

You consider stretches of equal numbers only after you read a number that terminates the current range of equal numbers. When all numbers are different, the size of that range is 1 and we don't print anything. If the range is larger than 1, print all indices in question.

Because you don't notice a change after reading the last number, you must check the last range separately after the main loop.

Comment: unfortunately I have to use an array

Comment: In that case, you have already an answer. But you can use this strategy, too, with arrays if you read the array first and then loop over the array with a `for` instead of reading in characters with a `while` loop. (Your original code reads and processes the array at the same time, which is close to reading the current value without storing an array, only that you can use a look-behind.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can put a non-numeric character in the [0] element of your array, you won't need a different test for the first element

```
int main (void)
{
    /* non-numeric in position 0 of data array */
    char myList[] = {'.','1','2','2','3','4','4','4','5','6','6'};
    int listSz = strlen(myList) -1;
    int n;

    /* check everything except last */
    for (n = 1; n < listSz; n++) {
        if(( myList[n] == myList[n +1]) || ( myList[n] == myList[n -1] )) {
            printf("%d . ", n);
        }
    }

    /* check last */
    if( myList[listSz] == myList[listSz -1] ) {
            printf("%d", n);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output: 2 . 3 . 5 . 6 . 7 . 9 . 10